# Existence of metric generating the same topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Now I have to prove, that there is a metric $d^*$ on $X$, which generates the same topology and satisfies
$$X \subseteq B_{d^*}(x,1) $$
for all $x \in X$.

What I know, is that generating the same topology is essentially saying that, the metrices $d$ and $d^*$ determine the same open balls. But how to deal with this further condition? Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Generating the same topology doesn't mean that they generate the same ball. For example, take $d$ induce by the $\ell^1$ norm on $\mathbb R^n$ and $d^*$ induce by the euclidian norm. They both generate ne same topology, but they don't have the same balls on $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $d'(x,y) = \min(d(x,y),\frac12)$ as the new metric for $(X,d)$.

First check that $d'$ is indeed a metric (it's called the *truncated* metric, as all old distances that were $>\frac12$ are just set to $\frac12$ in the new metric $d'$) and it's easy to see by the definitions that $\mathcal{T}(d)=\mathcal{T}(d')$ and $X \subseteq B_{d'}(x,1)$ for any $x$.

BTW it's more customary to take $1$ as the truncation point, but then the condition does not work for *open* balls. I could have chosen any truncation limit $>0$ in fact.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! You say "easy to see by the definitions..". What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Galois1763 what is the *definition* of $\mathcal{T}(d)$, the topology generated by $d$?

Comment: The topology generated by $d$, would be the open sets in X w.r.t to d. Right?

Comment: @Galois1763 yes. How are they defined?

Comment: FYI, when I see questions like these I wonder just how the asker (text author, teacher, etc.) expects someone just learning these abstract ideas to come up with something creative like this. Sure, a seasoned mathematician might think of this (e.g. from exposure to truncation of functions in Lebesgue integration or other places), but not someone just learning this. Of course, in today's world where students can so easily google for ideas, this aspect becomes less of a challenge, but I still think it would be better define the bounded metric(s) and then ask that the result be proved.

Comment: The open sets? Those are defined via open balls, which are elements of the topology.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro In my first year we had a course metrical topology and there we got (first week almost), after just learning the definition and verifying some metric functions as an exercise questions on whether the sum of metrics, product etc. is again a metric. The truncation idea was also studied right away. So it depdns on the text/notes you follow..

Comment: @Galois1763 Now check what open balls are in $d$ vs  $d'$ and how this can or cannot affect open sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you. So by showing that there are some radii s.t. all $d$-balls are contained in $d^*$- balls and vice versa, we can conclude the equivalence of these generated topologies?

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I thought this could be possible but didn't have any characters left to say so. Probably the $d/(1+d)$ metric (even with just $d$ as the usual absolute value metric on the reals) had been a previous example, and the student would find it (or the truncation idea) among previous metric examples. While I'm here, this [14 September 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/-qQj8KG6bd8/m/bNqduTBbPpYJ) might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Try $d^{\ast}(x,y)=\dfrac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$. The triangle inequality is as follows:

\begin{align*}
d^{\ast}(x,y)=1-\dfrac{1}{1+d(x,y)}
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
d^{\ast}(x,z)\leq d^{\ast}(x,y)+d^{\ast}(y,z)
\end{align*}
as $1-1/(1+\cdot)$ is an increasing sequence for positive reals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this candidate $d^*$ we would now prove, that $d$ and $d^*$ generate the same topology? My initial idea would be to show this with convergent sequences since we are in a metric space.

Comment: Yes, showing convergence both sides will do.